# Get id of parent naming container in template for in render / update attribute

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el, naming-containers

I have a template and in its Definition I use several forms and buttons.

The problem is the definition (define) xhtml file does not know the component hierarchy.

And for example I want to update the element "table2" in a different form in the same define file.

Template Insert:

```
<p:tabView id="nav"> <!-- nav -->
    <ui:insert name="content_nav">content navigation</ui:insert>
</p:tabView>
```

defines the first level of my hierarchy "nav"

Template define:

```
<ui:define name="content_nav">
    <h:form id="form1"> <!-- nav:form1 -->
        <h:dataTable id="table1"/> <!-- nav:form1:table1 -->
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.value}"/>
        <p:commandButton action="..." update="nav:form2:table2"/>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="form2">
        <h:dataTable id="table2"/> <!-- nav:form2:table2 -->
        <!-- other elements -->
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

In my define part I don't want to know "nav"!

How can I do this? or how can I move one naming component upwards?, or save the highest parent complete id in a variable?

sometimes i saw something like:

```
update=":table2"
```

But I could not find any informations about this?, the JavaEE 6 documentation just mentions the @ keywords.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ugly, but this should work out for you:

```
<p:commandButton action="..." update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:form2:table2" />
```

As you're already using PrimeFaces, an alternative is to use `#{p:component(componentId)}`, this helper function scans the entire view root for a component with the given ID and then returns its client ID:

```
<p:commandButton action="..." update=":#{p:component('table2')}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  #{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}  works fine.  But I hoped for a more elegant solution (syntax sugar). Similar to "../" for folderstructures.  Why did you still wrote a colon as a prefix?  I am new to jsf so I ask.  And I do not think its that ugly since using the unknown naming container clientId directly is more ugly since I could use that template multiple times. I think I will define myself a EL function to get the clientId of a sibling naming container.

Comment: The colon is the default `NamingContainer` separator character (which is overrideable by a context param though). When using it as prefix, it will be interpreted as "absolute" client ID, i.e. it's been resolved relative to the `UIViewRoot` instead of the current `NamingContainer` (which can be the composite, or datatable, or  form, etc). As to the nicer solution, use `p:component()` function instead (or homebrew one yourself).

Comment: p:component doesnt work for me. I'm really sad with this JSF behavior. Nothing works.

Comment: @MaikoID: Just press `Ask Question` with a decent [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) if you need help instead of sitting back doing nothing else than complaining and crying because you can't debug it yourself.

Comment: Great advice! It helped me with updating only specified component within an active tab in PrimeFaces TabView.

Comment: @BalusC does the same logic hold for `datasource` attribute of `p:droppable` ? I am struggling to map the correct datasource. Exact problem:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551952/datasource-mapping-when-draggable-and-droppable-in-different-naming-containers-a

Comment: @BalusC, once again a solution of yours saved my life: :#{p:component('..')} thingy is perfect. Your posts are a blessing! Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1):

ugly answer works well

```
update=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.namingContainer.clientId}:form2:table2
```

mainly more useful updating from opened dialog to parent datatable

Answer (score 1):

You may use `binding` attribute to declare EL variable bound to JSF component. Then you may access absolute client id of this component by using `javax.faces.component.UIComponent.getClientId()`. See example below:

```
<t:selectOneRadio 
   id="yourId"
   layout="spread"
   value="#{yourBean.value}"
   binding="#{yourIdComponent}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.values}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
<h:outputText>
   <t:radio for=":#{yourIdComponent.clientId}" index="0" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Click me">
    <f:ajax event="click" render="table" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: I wasn't precise enough. I want to update a particular element by its id, since not all elements are in the same form. I edited my post to make it clear. What does the @table do precisely? If both elements are siblings I could just use render="table" without @?

Comment: You could to use render="table".

Comment: What is render="table"...?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the solutions above I had the problem, that I had to dynamically generate the to-be-updated components (many) **based on server-side logic** (with maybe harder to find out nesting).

So the solution on the server-side is an **equivalent to `update=":#{p:component('table2')}"`**<sup>1</sup> which uses **`org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findComponentClientId( String designId )`**:

```
// UiPnlSubId is an enum containing all the ids used within the webapp xhtml.
// It could easily be substituted by a string list or similar.
public static String getCompListSpaced( List< UiPnlSubId > compIds ) {

    if ( compIds == null || compIds.isEmpty() )
        return "" ;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( ":" ) ;
    for ( UiPnlSubId cid : compIds )
        sb.append( ComponentUtils.findComponentClientId( cid.name() ) ).append( " " ) ;
    return sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() - 1 ).toString() ;  // delete suffixed space
}
```

called via some other method using it, e.g. like `... update="#{foo.getCompListComputed( 'triggeringCompId' )}"`.

<sup>1</sup>: first I tried without too much thinking to return `public static String getCompListSpaced0() { return ":#{p:component('table2')}" ; }` in an `... update="#{foo.getCompListSpaced0()}` expression, which of course (after thinking about how the framework works :) ) is not resolved (returned as is) and may cause the issues with it some users experienced. Also my Eclipse / JBoss Tools environment suggested to write `:#{p.component('table2')}` ("." instead of ":") which did not help - of course.