# Primefaces Dialog id can't bee seen from inside datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The following code implements a datatable inside a layout, in the datatable I added a menu Button whose menu Item updates the content of a dialog "outside the table" upon clicking it.
I get this error upon running the cde at the browser:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find component with identifier ":choice" referenced from "form:accounts:0:j_idt11".
```

Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="#{request.contextPath}/style.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:dialog header="You selected" widgetVar="dlg" id="choice" resizable="false" modal="true">
                    This item.
                </p:dialog>

        <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:dataTable id="accounts" var="account" value="pop" rowKey="1">

                    <p:column headerText="ID"></p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Option">

                        <p:growl id="messages" />
                        <p:menuButton value="">
                            <p:menuitem value="1" update="choice" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
                            <p:menuitem value="2" update="choice" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
                            <p:menuitem value="3" update="choice" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
                        </p:menuButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Update: When I add the dialog inside the databale it is seen by the menu button, but it either doesn't display properly, or opens and can't be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8634156/870122

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `<h:form>` will prepend its id to its components. To get rid of the error change your `<p:menuitem>` (all three) from

```
<p:menuitem value="1" update="choice" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
```

to

```
<p:menuitem value="1" update=":form:choice" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
```

Useful links

[How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)

[How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

[Get id of parent naming container in template for in render / update attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847096/get-id-of-parent-naming-container-in-template-for-in-render-update-attribute)