# datasource mapping doesn't work when droppable is in nested dataList

Tags: jsf, primefaces, draggable, jsf-2.2

This is the main view which contains the `draggable` items. In this view I have a `ui:include` for including a UI fragment that also has the drop area.

**mainView.xhtml**

```
<p:dataList id="outerList" var="varOuter" value="#{myVO.getOuterList()}"> 
    <div>
        <span>#{varOuter.someVal}</span>                                        
    </div>  

    <p:dataList id="innerList" var="innerVar" value="#{myVO.getInnerList()}">
        <div class="crew-list">
            <h:form>                                                            
                <h:panelGroup id="draggableItem" layout="block">
                        <span>#{innerVar.someVal}</span>                                                
                </h:panelGroup>                                                                                                                                                             
                <p:draggable for="draggableItem" opacity="0.5" scope="ab"
                    revert="true" helper="clone" appendTo="@(body)" zindex="4" >                                                        
                </p:draggable>                                                      
            </h:form>   
         </div>
     </p:dataList>
</p:dataList>   
 ...

<ui:include src="fragment.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="param" value="#{paramVal}" />                                            
</ui:include>
```

**fragment.xhtml**

```
<p:dataList id="list" var="pos" value="#{myVO.getPositions()}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{!pos.isFilled()}">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="dropArea">
                <span>Drop Here</span>              
            </h:panelGroup>    
            <p:droppable for="dropArea" hoverStyleClass="active"
                    scope="ab" datasource=":outerList:innerList">
                <p:ajax listener="#{crewChangeVO.onDrop}" update="list" />
                <f:attribute name="index" value="#{rowIndex}" />
            </p:droppable>
        </ui:fragment>
</p:dataList>
```

Now the problem that I run into is that, I am unable to map the `datasource` on the droparea correctly. Without datasource the drag-drop works but I don't get the data (dragged object) in my bean method and I need a way to know which object was dragged.

Would appriciate any input on how to achive this functionality.

**Update**
Using a single(non-nested) dataList as the source with a form outside it works. But the problem is that it doesn't work for a nested list. So, for now I am proceeding with design changes and removing the nested list.

Comment: What if you use a form on a broader 'scope' and not inside the datalist for each repeating item? Is the ui:fragment relevant? Are you sure referencing the datasource via `:outerList:innerList` is correct? Does it work if you don't 'include' it but directly use it?

Comment: If I remove the form and just use the `datasource="outerList"` it starts invoking the method with data being set. Rest combinations didn't work. `ui:fragment` is relevant in my case as this is a small chunk of html that I have posted, there is more logic in the view. I am not sure if `:outerList:innerList` is correct. That's what I need help with. Linking the datasource

Comment: why do you remove the form AND change the datasource? That is not what I intended to test... Try them one by one... Cheers

Comment: haha.. I did test them one by one. they didn't work. So, apparently the nested lists are creating a problem in referencing the draggable object. I am quite sure that `:outerList:innerList` is incorrect. So I am now trying other incremental approaches to get to the reference correctly.

Comment: So using a single list (non-nested) dataList as the source with a form inside it and an using an include does work? If so, you can improve the title since you narrowed down the problem in a better way... What is you PF version? If it is 6.1, maybe try a 6.2-SNAPSHOT from source and if that still fails,  can you create a clean, small [mcve]...

Comment: Have updated the question. Will try to create an example demonstrating what works and what doesn't as soon as I can. Thanks for your counter questions, they helped in uncovering the real issue :)

Comment: Maybe you need to take the 'index' into account of the inner datalist? (tried e.g. if using a ui:repeat works?)